# Как правильно хранить список объектов в c#?

Tags: xml, классы, объекты

Возникла проблема сохранения динамического списка, элементами которого являются объекты класса. А именно не могу понять, где размещать созданный список объектов - в статическом классе в виде поля класса, в публичном классе в виде поля класса.
Почему возникла такая проблема? Из неё вытекает другая, а именно: частично повторяющееся название класса. Приходится создавать 2 класса - class Object  и class Objects. Пишу: `Object obj = new Object()` в первом случае и `Objects objs = new Objects()`. Разве это корректно? Видел на ютубе, что так делают, но не объясняют, почему.
Всё, что я хочу узнать, так это правильный ли подход я использую (описываю класс одиночного объекта, а потом группы объектов, если придется), или используется что-то иное?

Вот, набросал работающий код, если кто не понял моих опасений:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var students = new Students();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            students.StudentList.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Vladislav", LastName = "Volkov", Age = 24 });
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

      public class Students
    {
          public List<Student> StudentList;
          public Students()
          {
              StudentList = new List<Student>();
          }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov, если Students не несет в себе дополнительной логики, то  хранить надо сразу в виде List<T>. Если логика есть - "найти студентов с ситуацией печальней Х", например - то класс-обертка все-таки нужен. Что до названия - лучше называть StudentList или StudentCollection просто потому, что названия разнятся в одну букву и можно довольно лекго случайно написать более короткое название вместо более длинного.

Comment: м-м... понятно = (((